# How to initialize External Image with Margins for convolution?

Tags: halide

Constraints:
 1. Have a pointer to an image with margins of size (ImHeight,ImWidth)
 2. Filter size (FH,FW) ; FH,FW are odd
 3. ActualImageHeight = ImHeight-2*(FH/2); ActualImageWidth = ImWidth-2*(FW/2);

How To:

1. Initialize image with the pointer such that image(0,0) is pixel(0,0) and not the margin pixel ?
2. Define a schedule without using boundary conditions / clamping - since the given image pointer memory already accounts for the margins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the minimum coordinate of the image. You didn't state if you are using JIT or AOT, but here is a JIT implementation.

```
Halide::Image input( ImWidth + 2 * FW, ImHeight + 2 * FH ), output;
input.set_min( -FW, -FH );
Func f;
f(x,y) = ( input( x - FW, y - FH ) + input( x + FW - 1, y + FH - 1 ) ) / 2;
output = f.realize( ImWidth, ImHeight );
```

For AOT:

- Use `ImageParam` for `input`.
- Use `Param<int>` for `ImWidth` and `ImHeight` to have them be parameters to the AOT function.
- Use `int` for `ImWidth` and `ImHeight` to have them be baked into the the AOT function.
- Use `set_bounds` and `set_stride` for all dimensions of `input` and `f.output_buffer()`. These take `Expr`s so will accept `ImWidth + 2 * FW` if `ImWidth` is a `Param<int>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was not setting the set_min correctly.